# Home page of wordpress site redirecting...htaccess issues

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have installed wordpress in a directory 'test-admin'

In that directory I have the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test-site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
AuthName "test-site"
```

In the main public html directory I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(test-site) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/newdomain\.com" [R=301,L]

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

So everything on my public html in 'mydomain' i wish to redirect to 'newdomain' except for the 'test-admin' folder....this is working apart from the home page in the test admin folder

Any ideas what I have done wrong?  It is wordpress multisite installed in 'test-admin'...latest wp version.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

it's now fixed, very random, I just went in and played with home page and customisation in wp admin and it fixed it randomly, no idea what was wrong.